# How do I forward the SAME port to 2 Computers in router linksys E1000

Tags: router, port-forwarding

I cloned my question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605866/how-do-i-forward-the-same-port-to-2-computers-in-router-linksys-e1000)

I use linksys router E1000. I have 2 server Ubuntu in 2 Computer, and I want to forward its over the internet at the same time (same port is 80).

How do I forward the SAME port to 2 Computers in router linksys E1000 ?

Comment: You can't have port 80 on the outside forward to two separate destinations on the inside.

Comment: And they're both in the wrong place.

Answer (score 6):

You can't (with that equipment). You will have to forward it to a system running a reverse proxy that redirects it based on other information (e.g. the `Host` header).

Answer (score -1):

> How do I forward the SAME port to 2 computers.

Generally you do not. The unique target is a combination of IP:port. You can not use two identical values while having each of those unique.

HTTP is an exception though, it uses a triple {IP:port:hostname in protocol}.  You can formward to a single computer running a webserver/proxy. And then based on that forward is indirectly to the destination host.

Note that this is the same as Ignacio already said, but with more background.

Also note that this does not depened on a router or a brnad of router.